# Flutter TextField is not reading the letter č

Tags: flutter

Steps to Reproduce:-

Select language Croatian or keyboard that has letters for Croatian language.

Type č. It has problem with letter č.. it doesn't recognise it.. ć š ž đ are OK

Please find the code below:-

```
                          TextFormField(
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          hintText: _viewMode
                              ? ''
                              : AppMessages.WriteMemoryHintText,
                          hintMaxLines: 5,
                          hintStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                          border: InputBorder.none,
                          focusedBorder: InputBorder.none,
                          enabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                          errorBorder: InputBorder.none,
                          disabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                        ),
                        autofocus: true,
                        maxLines: null,
                        textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.sentences,
                        readOnly: _viewMode || _requestLoading,
                        style: CommonStyleHelper.bodyText1Style(context),
                        controller: _memoryDescriptionController,
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                        onChanged: (value) => _onChangeCheck(),
                      ),
```

Answer (score 1):

It's the issue with the font I'm using in my project. Fixed it by using the default font.